# How do i fix command liveshare.start not found on VS Code?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm using Linux Ubuntu 22.04.1. I've already installed the Live Share extension on VS Code. However, when I press the Share or Join buttons, nothing happens. I've tried running live share from my command palette, but I get an error. I've already went through some answers given on stackoverflow and other platforms regarding this issue, but nothing works. Would love some help. This is the error message I'm getting. [command liveshare.start not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1uTe.png)

Comment: I get liveshare.join not found myself. Guessing it is the same issue.